# How to evaluate $\arctan(1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I thought

$$\arctan(1) = \dfrac{\arcsin(1)}{\arccos(1)}$$

Sin hits 1 at $\pi/2$, and Cos hits 1 at $0$ and $2\pi$

So $\dfrac{\arcsin(1)}{\arccos(1)} = \dfrac{1}{4}$

But the solution says it is $\pi/4$...

Comment: Why did you think arctan = arcsin/cosin? tan =sin/cos and arctan = inverse (tan). Inverses almost *never* preserve division. E.g.. a/b -5 $\ne $ (a-5)/(b-5) and log $e^5/e^3 \ne 5/3$ etc.

Comment: @fleablood Because I am stupid?

Comment: Eek.  You're not stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By (one) definition, the arctangent of $1$ is the unique number in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ whose tangent is $1.$ I suspect that you already know that $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ for all real numbers $x.$ Consequently, $\arctan 1$ is the unique number in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ whose sine and cosine are equal. Depending on your definition of sine and cosine, it may be more or less obvious that $$\arctan(1)=\frac\pi4.$$

Answer (score 4):

$\arctan(x)\neq \frac{\arcsin(x)}{\arccos(x)}$

$\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ because $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$. The latter you can see in a so called "45-45-90" triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
\tan \left( \frac\pi4\right)=\frac{\sin\left( \frac\pi4\right)}{\cos\left( \frac\pi4\right)} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}2}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}2}=1
$$ giving
$$
\frac\pi4=\arctan (1).
$$

Answer (score 0):

In order for the inverse of cosine to be defined, it must be restricted to a domain for which it is one-to-one. Therefore, we restrict the domain of $\cos$ to be from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. So the range of $\cos^{-1} $ is as follows.

$$-\pi \leq \cos^{-1}(y) \leq \pi$$.

So $2\pi \neq cos^{-1}(1)$. Indeed, $\cos^{-1}(1) = 0$, making the equation

$$\frac{\sin^{-1}(1)}{\cos^{-1}(1)} = \frac{\pi/2}{0}$$

undefined.

To find $\tan^{-1}(1)$, we need to find $x$ so that $\tan(x) =1$. Thus,

$$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = 1$$

implies that $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$. So $x$ must be $k \pi /4$ where $k$ is any integer. But as we are trying to solve for $x$ so that $\tan^{-1}(1) = x$, $x$ has to be in the range of $-\pi$ to $\pi$, i.e., $x = \pi/4$.

Comment: Use only one dollar sign for inline math.

Comment: @Deusovi  Oops my bad. Bad habits from editing on Piazza. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not stupid. You made an adventurous generalisation hoping that a new functional relation F should still respect the earlier ones.

$$\frac{  f(x)}{g(x) }=\frac{ F( f(x))} {F(g(x) )} $$

Unfortunately not true, in general it cannot be brought on to a new stage still respecting earlier functional relationships.If F is multiplication by a constant, then of course it is OK.